# JMeter not accepting Valid Regex, causing nothing to be posted

Tags: jmeter, regex

I'd like to prefix this question with the fact that i'm a novice when it comes to Jmeter and Regex.

I have created a test plan for an ASP .Net application, which consists of a GET request, with a Regular expression extractor to grab a token, then a POST request, with a RegEx User Parameter to take the extracted token and use it in the request:

[image]

In the get request's respnse, there is a value of __RequestVerificationToken, which i am capturing with the following Regex (tested in tree Listner and is Validated):

```
(?<=Set-Cookie: __RequestVerificationToken=).{108}
```

So, it looks for "__RequestVerificationToken=" then gets the 108 characters after it.

[image]

Regular expression extractor:

[image]

Parameters in POST Request:

[image]

The RegEx user parameter i'm using is:

[image]

But when i run the test, the request post data returns:

[image]

I've used https://www.regextester.com/ for testing my RegEx and it correctly gets the token, so i'm wondering if JMeter just doesn't accept this?

*Note:* apologies for using images rather than text, i couldn't think of a good way to show the data.

Comment: I am not sure your regexp is valid. There is much easier way to capture the token since it is between `=` and `;`. Can you test your expression here https://regex101.com/ and save your trials and share as saved link?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for responding. I've tested it on the suggested link. It does look to be matching. please see here: https://regex101.com/r/1ljlXj/1

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your `__RequestVerificationToken` comes as a [HTTP Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) hence it makes sense to use [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)

1. Add the next line to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   CookieManager.save.cookies=true
   ```
2. Add HTTP Cookie Manager to your Test Plan
3. That's it, now you can access the token value as `${COOKIE____RequestVerificationToken}` where required

Check out [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide/) article for more information

Comment: "Add the next line to user.properties file" which line?

Comment: Thanks for the catch, updated

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this for **regex**:

```
__RequestVerificationToken=(.+?);
```

Comment: Hi, The above RegEx has given me the desired result, if i change the RegEx extractor template to $1$ in my scenario. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are expecting a valid JSON, so instead of RegEx, you could use [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) and/or [JSON Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Assertion), for which extra spacing will not matter.

Example if response data is

`{"RequestVerificationToken":"12345"}`

and specify ***JSON extractor*** and place under the ***HTTP Header manager***  and send JSON path as `$.RequestVerificationToken` and you got the result variable `RequestVerificationToken` with Expacted value.